# Generate JMeter Summary or aggregate report using JMeter command line execution

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am using below JMeter commandline to execute JMeter tests and generate csv file

jmeter -n -t "E:\New folder\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\JMeterProject\Test.jmx" -l "E:\New folder\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\JMeterResult\Result.csv"

Is there any way to generate Aggregate or Summary report by passing any options to above command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, you will need to run another command and it assumes having [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) plugin installed

1. Run your test and create [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles)

   ```
   jmeter -n -t "E:\New folder\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\JMeterProject\Test.jmx" -l "E:\New folder\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\JMeterResult\Result.csv"
   ```
2. Run JMeterPluginsCMD to create CSV version of the Summary Report out of the .jtl results file:

   ```
   JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-csv "E:\New folder\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\JMeterResult\Summary.csv" --input-jtl "E:\New folder\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\JMeterResult\Result.csv" --plugin-type AggregateReport
   ```

More information: [How to Use the JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeterpluginscmd)